# Django Redirect returns 200, but page does not redirect

Tags: django, redirect, google-oauth

I have a django project where I am doing google oauth2. I click on a google signin button, I receive a post request from Googles api, and then I interpret that request and want to redirect the user to a page where they can create their own account.

Right now everything appears to work up until the redirect is suppose to happen. The terminal where my django project is running shows that it was successful (the print statements I wrote to confirm it reaches the render function work, and I see a 200 response also), but I remain on the login page.

I am wondering if the redirect and render are happening on another website session, or otherwise somewhere besides where the user is currently on the website?

Here is the code for my google webhook:

```
token = request.POST.get('idtoken')
        print(token)

        try:
            idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
            print(idinfo)
            print('got past token')
            google_user_id = idinfo['sub']
            google_email = idinfo['email']
            
            try: # authenticates user who already exists as a google signed in user.
                user_from_sub = User.objects.get(google_sub_id=google_user_id)
                user = user_from_sub.get_user_object()
                if user.type == Types.BUSINESS:
                    backend = 'user_accounts.auth_backends.BusinessAuthBackend'
                    login(request, user, backend=backend) # TODO: add auth backend cred
                elif user.type == Types.CONSUMER:
                    backend = 'user_accounts.auth_backends.ConsumerAuthBackend'
                    login(request, user, backend=backend) # TODO: add auth backend cred
                else:
                    login(request, user)        
                print('logged in')
                return redirect(reverse('home'))

            except: # user doesn't yet exist, with specified sub id

                idinfo['account_type'] = 'consumer'

                print(request.GET)
                print('creating account')
                url = f'http://localhost:8000/oauth2/google/account-creation/?{urllib.parse.urlencode(idinfo)}'
                return redirect(url)
        except ValueError:
            print("authentication failed due to an error")
```

Here is the code for my account creation view:

```
def create_google_oauth_user_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    """"""
    print('hello')
    print(request.GET)
    print(request.body)
    account_type = request.GET.get('account_type')
    idinfo = request.GET
    print(f'idinfo: {idinfo}')
    if idinfo: # user data was passed
        user = User.objects.filter(email=idinfo['email']).first()
        if user:
            user = user.get_user_object()
    else: # no user_info was passed
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    if account_type == 'business': # add to special business sign up page
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = BusinessGoogleSignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES, idinfo=idinfo)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Account Creation Successful')
                login(request, data, backend='user_accounts.auth_backends.BusinessAuthBackend')
                return redirect(reverse('accounts:add_profile_picture', kwargs={'user_id': data.id}))
        else:
            form = BusinessGoogleSignUpForm(idinfo=idinfo)

    elif account_type == 'consumer': # for regular consumer users
        print('got to consumer')
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ConsumerGoogleSignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES, idinfo=idinfo)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Account Creation Successful')
                login(request, data, backend='user_accounts.auth_backends.ConsumerAuthBackend')
                return redirect(reverse('accounts:add_profile_picture', kwargs={'user_id': data.id}))
        else:
            form = ConsumerGoogleSignUpForm(idinfo=idinfo)
    else: # no user type was specified
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    print('got to context')

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'oauth/google/account_creation.html', context)
```

As it stands the code always gets to the 'got to context' print statement and returns 200. Any advice or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an else statement for if the form isn't valid in post requests? If I'm reading it right then, if your form isn't valid, it will just continuously re-render with a pre-populated form with the data you submitted.